# Javac does not see external libraries

Tags: java, classpath, javac, jsch

I'm trying to compile a small app to test out a JSCH connection on Windows 10 running Java 1.6. There is only one Java source file. It imports the JSCH library however at compile time I get the error message "package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist" on each import statement and "cannot find symbol" on each reference.

I have tried...

```
javac JSchTest.java  
javac -cp . JSchTest.java  
javac -classpath . JSchTest.java  
javac -cp jsch-0.1.44.jar JSchTest.java  
javac -cp lib\jsch-0.1.44.jar JSchTest.java  
javac -cp *.jar JSchTest.java  
javac -cp "lib\*" JSchTest.java  
javac -cp "lib\*:." JSchTest.java
```

My code...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class JSchTest {
  private JSch jsch = null;
  private Session session = null;
  private Channel ch = null;
  private ChannelSftp chsftp = null;
  private String user = "username";
  private String code = "password";
  private String host = null;
  private static PrintStream out = System.out;

  public JSchTest() {
    jsch = new JSch();

    if(getConnected()) {
      out.println("Connection successful");
      chsftp.disconnect();
      session.disconnect();
    } else out.println("Error: Failed to connect to server\n");

    out.println("\nExiting...");
    chsftp = null;
    ch = null;
    session = null;
    jsch = null;
    System.exit(0);
  }

  /** This routine creates an sftp connection with the remote host. */
  public boolean getConnected() {
    int port = 22;

    try {
      session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
      session.setPassword(code);
      java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
      config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
      session.setConfig(config);
      session.connect();
      ch = session.openChannel("sftp");
      ch.connect();
      chsftp = (ChannelSftp)ch;
      return true;
    } catch (JSchException jse) {
      out.println("JSchException: Error connecting to server " + host + ": " + jse);
    }

    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JSchTest();
  }
}
```

When I run...

```
javac -cp jsch-0.1.44.jar JSchTest.java
```

I get...

```
JSchTest.java:6: package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist  
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
```

Comment: If you tried both `-cp jsch-0.1.44.jar` and `-cp lib\jsch-0.1.44.jar`, then it looks to me like you don't even know *where* the jar file is. Where is that jar file, relative to the current working directory when you run `javac`? --- Also, have you tried to check the content of the jar file to verify that it contains a `com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.class` file?

Comment: The files jsch-0.1.44.jar and JSchTest.java are both in the same folder.
The jsch-0.1.44.jar is a good file and does contain all the classes needed.
Thanks.

Comment: Really?!? Because the `jsch-0.1.44.jar` I can find on [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.44) is **empty** (size: 2 KB), which was fixed with version [0.1.44-1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.44-1) (size: 208 KB).

Comment: The `jsch-0.1.44.jar` file I'm using was downloaded from [jcraft.com](http://www.jcraft.com) and has been in use for some time on some legacy apps. I see their current version is **0.1.55**. So I download that and it didn't make any difference.
It will compile in NetBeans but not from the command line so I don't believe there's a problem with the Java code either. I feel it has something to do with the way I'm using the compiler. JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME are both set. I've tried JDK versions **jdk1.8.0_192**, **jdk1.8.0_172**, **jdk.1.7.0_80** and **jdk1.6.0_45**.